# Android Studio SQLite Query to listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have spent days going through the forums and have come up with no solution.

I am trying to retrieve all records from a database and show them in a listView

```
public class list_loans extends Activity {

    ListView loanList;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_loans);

        //Instantiate Database helper
        DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
        ArrayList<personObject> myArray = new ArrayList<>();
        //Open writable database
        SQLiteDatabase db = myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor resultSet = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM borrower", null);

        //TODO: Print out single list of item, not list for each item!**
        if (resultSet != null) {

            personObject myPerson = null;
            if (resultSet.moveToFirst()) {
                do {

                    String nameOut = resultSet.getString(1);
                    String phoneOut = resultSet.getString(2);
                    String addressOut = resultSet.getString(3);
                    Integer itemID = resultSet.getInt(4);
                    String itemType = resultSet.getString(5);
                    String itemDesc = resultSet.getString(6);

                    myPerson = new personObject(nameOut, phoneOut, addressOut, itemID, itemType,
                            itemDesc);

                }while (resultSet.moveToNext());
            }
            myArray.add(myPerson);
            loanList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.loanList);
            //TODO: loop through array and add each item to list, instead of entire array to list**
            loanList.setAdapter(new listAdapter(this, myArray));
            resultSet.close();
            db.close();
        }
    }
```

My adapter:

```
package com.creativenative.jonathan.loanme;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
* Created by Jonathan on 7/17/2015.
*/
class listAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
ArrayList data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public listAdapter(Context context, ArrayList data) {
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return data;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi = convertView;
    if (vi == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        TextView text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText(data.toString());
    return vi;
}
}
```

The expected output is:

```
Header Item 1
Item 1 details

Header Item 2
Item 2 details
```

Actual output:

```
Header item 1
Item 1 details
Header item 2
Item 2 details

Header item 1
Item 1 details
Header item 2
Item 2 details
```

Each time i add an item to the database, it adds another list item that contains everything in the database:

Add another item output:

```
Header item 1
Item 1 details
Header item 2
Item 2 details
Header item 3
Item 3 details

Header item 1
Item 1 details
Header item 2
Item 2 details
Header item 3
Item 3 details

Header item 1
Item 1 details
Header item 2
Item 2 details
Header item 3
Item 3 details
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get each item in it's own individual spot on the list view. Any help is much appreciated, as usual...Also, I know this problem has been addressed before, but even going through the other posts has not helped.

Comment: It would be really helpful to know why this post keeps getting down votes. I show research effort and it is useful.

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter, change

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return data;
}
```

to

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return data.get(position);
}
```

Because currently, the `getItem(int position)` method is returning the whole data set instead of the item at the requested position.

**Edit**

The behaviour you are expecting is due to your loop. Have a look at the following code snippet of yours:

```
personObject myPerson = null;
if (resultSet.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        String nameOut = resultSet.getString(1);
        String phoneOut = resultSet.getString(2);
        String addressOut = resultSet.getString(3);
        Integer itemID = resultSet.getInt(4);
        String itemType = resultSet.getString(5);
        String itemDesc = resultSet.getString(6);

        myPerson = new personObject(nameOut, phoneOut, addressOut, itemID, itemType,
                itemDesc);

    }while (resultSet.moveToNext());
}

myArray.add(myPerson);
//The above line of code is executed after your loop has finished. 
//The result of this is that you only add the latest entry from your DB.
//Furthermore, your adapter is only displaying this data.
```

Your loop should look like this:

```
personObject myPerson = null;
if (resultSet.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        String nameOut = resultSet.getString(1);
        String phoneOut = resultSet.getString(2);
        String addressOut = resultSet.getString(3);
        Integer itemID = resultSet.getInt(4);
        String itemType = resultSet.getString(5);
        String itemDesc = resultSet.getString(6);

        myPerson = new personObject(nameOut, phoneOut, addressOut, itemID, itemType,
                itemDesc);

        myArray.add(myPerson);
    }while (resultSet.moveToNext());
}
```

These changes will add every entry from your DB to your list.

**Edit 2**

So, in your adapter...

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi = convertView;
    if (vi == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

    TextView text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
    text.setText(data.toString()); //this makes no sense. You are converting an ArrayList to String?
    return vi;
}
```

change to

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi = convertView;
    if (vi == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

    TextView text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
    text.setText(data.get(position).getNameOut()); //Or whatever you want to display
    return vi;
}
```

Comment: This solution makes progress of a sort. Now it only shows a single item in the list, but it only shows the last item from the db, and not all items...

Comment: Have a look at your underlying data. When you create your list (myArray), and assign your adapter to that list, what is in that list? @Jon Smith

Comment: @Jon Smith hint: it's only one object in the list. Why? Because you loop through your resultset, but do not add every entry to your list, only the last. I'm on my phone, but when I get to a comp I'll edit my answer to show you

Comment: after the edit it goes back to original output. It is adding the entire list to each list item, so I will have item 1 and item 2, item 1 and item 2. If I add a third item, it would be item 1 and item 2 and item 3, item 1 and item 2 and item 3, item 1 and item 2 and item 3...adding an item to each list item and adding a new list item each time.

Comment: Keep Edit 1 and add Edit 2. @JonSmith

Comment: LOL, of course, I kept edit 1 and added edit 2, and the output went back to the original output. This is why I came to stack for the answer, I have tried everything I can think of, everything I could find on SO, and can only get everything (original output) or only the last item...